# Firefox simple extension to create window as an popup

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i would like to create simple below window on firefox. i'm trying to develop simple extension for some feature. now i can not create window like with `windows` window instead of [Popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup) and i can not find any document about that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the source for the pixel perfect extension as it does something similar to your ( somewhat vague ) description:

https://github.com/firebug/pixel-perfect/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'window/utils'` SDK API and its `openDialog()` function:

```
require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
  url: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
  name: 'My pop-up window!',
  features: 'height      = 180, ' +
            'width       = 320, ' +
            'toolbar     = no, ' +
            'menubar     = no, ' +
            'scrollbars  = no, ' +
            'resizable   = no, ' +
            'location    = no, ' +
            'directories = no, ' +
            'status      = no'
});
```

This API is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils

And here you can find full list of supported features for `openDialog()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/open